# Swift 3 generic extension constraint with generic parameter

Tags: swift, generics

Here is what I want to achieve:

I have a generic struct `struct Future<Element> {}` and another generic struct `Response<T> {}`. I want to write a method that is in extension for `Future` that is only valid when `Element` is `Response<T>`. It doesn't matter what `T` is. So here is the code:

`extension Future where Element == Response { }`

But swift compiler complains that **Reference to generic type 'Response' requires arguments in <...>**. Is there another way to achieve this in swift?

Answer (score 14):

I know it's been a while since you asked, but I was trying to solve a similar problem just now... What about writing the extension this way, as a generic function with the constraints you want?

```swift
struct Future<Element> {
    let elem: Element
}
struct Response<T> {
    let t: T
}

extension Future {
    func newFunc<X>() where Element == Response<X> {
        print("My Element is a Response: \(elem.t)")
    }
}
```

Comment: Feels like forever I've been looking for this answer… and it's so damn obvious! Thanks Peter!

Answer (score 3):

One possible solution is creating a dummy protocol which `Response` would conform to:

```
protocol ResponseObject {}

struct Response<T> {}
extension Response: ResponseObject {}
```

Then you'll be able to check against protocol conformance in your extensions:

```
extension Future where Element: ResponseObject {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Do you know of a better way now, esp. with Swift 4?